# making bottom bar in android

Tags: android, button

I am trying to make **bottom bar** that should look like below image. i.e., they should be separate only with line exactly like below image.

[image]

**My output is like below image**

[image]

**My code:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonbar"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/ok" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel"  />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have imported an example and it's looking like the first image. But when I used the same code in my project and tested on the same emulator, it's looking like the second one. Can some one suggest what should be done to look like in the first image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, it will give a result like the first image.
But I did some color changes only.

Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonbar"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/ok"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Update: This is what you need.

Edited:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttonbar"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/okButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@android:string/ok"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@android:string/cancel"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Increase the size of dp as much as you want to show the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is no line separation with this answer above the bar and between the buttons :( as I shown in the first image. I wanna know why it worked with the example and why it didn't when I used the same code in my project.

Comment: Just add some view between buttons @anoo

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already know this view and background nulls. I wanna know why it didn't work as in the example with nothing added extra :( Anyways, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/ok"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"  />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for more info.. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Comment: Sorry, this style requires api 11, but my project min is 8. But with the same code I pasted in the question, that bottom bar is getting in the example that I have run. That too if we borderless button, there is no line separation between two buttons

Comment: I have another solution for you... create some transparent images(of small width and small height). Then set as background to your buttons. android:background="@drawable/transparent_image"